# Занесение данных из почты домена в базу mysql

Tags: php, mysql, email

Подскажите, каким способом можно сохранять письма пришедшие с сайта в почту домена и занести их в базу? Знаю это как-то реализовано у тикет систем, когда при получении письма на почту создаётся новый тикет.

Comment: Сервер выделен, можете настраивать собственный почтовый сервис? Если не выделен, какие протоколы доступны? POP3, IMAP?

Comment: Не понятно, вам целиком письма надо сохранять в базу и что бы imap/pop из базы их отдавали клиентам. Или нужна только информация о письмах в базе ? Лично у меня стандартный delivery агент для старого злого sendmail подменен на собственный perl скрипт, который в том числе кладет некоторую информацию в БД.

Comment: Честно говоря я уже разобрался, что нужно использовать imap для получения писем, а вот не получается вытащить само тело письма почему-то.